# Condition in Hive based on two tables

Tags: sql, hive

I have two tables in hive as below

Table1 - **Customers**

```
Cust_id       Purchase        Purchase_detail
123           buy             Cheap
354           no_buy          No Interest
985           buy             Deal of the day
456           buy             Found Cheaper
978           no_buy          Interested
```

Table2 - **Cust_buy_details**

```
Cust_dec       Cust_det
buy            Interested
buy            Cheap
no_buy         Found Cheaper
no_buy         No Interest
no_buy         Other Faults
```

Now I want to populate a new field called **details_filter** with a condition when Customers.Purchase = Cust_buy_details.Cust_dec  then  Customers.Purchase_detail should match with anyone of Cust_buy_details.Cust_det else null.
Example - Cust_id : 985 has Purchase: buy which match with Cust_buy_details.Cust_dec but Purchase_detail does not match with Cust_buy_details.Cust_det then I want the result of the new field to be null.

I'd like to see the result as below.

```
Cust_id       Purchase        Purchase_detail      details_filter
123           buy             Cheap                Cheap
354           no_buy          No Interest          No Interest
985           buy             Deal of the day      null
456           buy             Found Cheaper        null
978           no_buy          Interested           null
```

Can someone help me in writing this condition in Hive??

Comment: Edit our question and show the results you want.

Comment: Sure @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a `left join`:

```
select c.*, cbd.cust_det
from customers c left join
     cust_buy_details cbd
     on c.purchase = cbd.cust_dec and c.purchase_detail = cbd.cust_det;
```

Comment: It Works.., this is the fastest response I've ever seen on stack overflow.  Awesome, superb Helpful......!! Thank you Gordon....